# Canceling AsyncTask from AsyncTask ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

(this is Not about nullpointer):
I have a progress bar in AsyncTask and i added a cancel button to cancel asynctask.

i can cancel the asynctask from outside  the asynctask but i need to implement cancel function in progressdialog which is implemented under asynctask.

So the question is how to cancel asynctask with cancel button which is implemented in progressdialog under asynctask?

plse do check in "doInBackground"..the asynctask is not getting cancel

Download_result.java class:

```
public class Download_result extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>{
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context context;
String pdfFile;


Download_result(Context context, String pdfFile){
    this.context=context;
    this.pdfFile=pdfFile;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(200);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Download_result.this.cancel(true);  
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      //given below
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);       
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.cancel();        

}
}
```

[image]

my "doInBackground" method:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {      

            String url_1=params[0];
            int file_length=0;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(url_1);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                file_length=urlConnection.getContentLength();
                filesize=file_length;
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File new_folder = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/xxx");


                File input_file = new File(new_folder,pdfFile);
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),8192);
                byte[] data=new byte[1024];
                int total=0,count=0;
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(input_file);
                while ((count=inputStream.read(data))!=-1){
                    total+=count;
                    outputStream.write(data,0,count);


                    int progress= (total*200)/file_length;
                    downloadedsize=total;

                    publishProgress(progress);
                    if(isCancelled()){
                        break;  or return null; // same result
                    }


                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        return null;//"Download completed!";
    }
```

Comment: post the crash log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please show the logcat and the code which causes the NPE. Be sure to clearly point out the exact line of code where the crash occurs.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice EDITED CHECK....plse check

Comment: `at com.*********.result.Download_result$1.onClick(Download_result.java:62)` what is line 62 of Download_result.java?

Comment: if(isCancelled()){
            break; // Why break, you must return null
       }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not dismissed the dialog in cancel button press.. also use `setButton` instead

try this:

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(200);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          download.cancel(true);
           downloadstatus=false;  //add boolean check
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      });
        progressDialog.show();
}
```

To cancel an Async Task use:

```
 Public Download_result download;
 download = new Download_result();
 download.execute();
download.cancel(true);
```

try this in `doInbackGround`()

```
 while ((count=inputStream.read(data))!=-1){

                if(!your_AsyncTask.isCancelled() ||  downloadstatus !=false){
                    total+=count;
                    outputStream.write(data,0,count);
                    int progress= (total*200)/file_length;
                    downloadedsize=total;

                    publishProgress(progress);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: same result...actualy i was using setButton too..see my edited post, check where i am getting nullpointer

Comment: @wangz what is your `Download_result.java:62` line?

Comment: Download_result.java is a class where i implementing the above code(asynctask), and "download.cancel(true)" is in 62line...

Comment: to properly cancel the async task you have to use..`myTask.cancel(true);` as your `download` is null it causes the exception..

Comment: thanx, though i have implemented what Code-Apprentice suggested but still the logic is same and now i am not getting any null pointer exception. but any way the asynctask is not getting cancel i am getting the downloaded file in file manager. i want it to be cancel in halfway. i might have made some mistake in my "doInBackground" plse check for me..plse plse

Comment: both myTask.cancel(true) and download.cancel(true) are same, you are declaring asynctask as myTask but i am declaring as download..only variable is different but reference is same.

Comment: that's y i said i have corrected it (now i am not getting null pointer exeption). Now i am not passing asynctask(download) as parameter. plse see ma edited post.

Comment: tanx you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

```
Download_result(Context context, String pdfFile,Download_result download)
```

It does not make any sense to send a `Download_result` as a parameter to its own constructor. You can never have a valid reference to pass the constructor. You should change this constructor to

```
Download_result(Context context, String pdfFile)
```

Every method of `Download_result` already has a reference to a `Download_result` object called `this`. Since you need access to it in an inner class, use `Download_result.this`:

```
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Download_result.this.cancel(true);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, now i am not getting nullpointer exception. But still asynctask doesn't get cancel. i get downloaded file in file manager. I may have made some mistake in "doInBackground"..plse check for me.

Comment: @wangz That is because you only check `isCancelled()` once just as `doInBackground()` begins. You need to check this value periodically in order to detect if the AsyncTask is cancelled.

Comment: @wangz You should post a new question since your original one was already answered. Feel free to link to this question in order to provide context.

Comment: the main question was to cancel asynctask which is still not solved. :(

Comment: @wangz The original question was about an NPE. This **has** been solved. Please post a new question for further help. Comments and edits are for clarification, not to completely change the question.

Comment: k i am posting, do reply to my post

Answer (score 0):

Create a "boolean keepGoing" in your AsyncTask and set it to true. Within your "doInBackground" procedure poll it regularly and return, if false. Bind the cancel button to a setter within the AsyncTask which sets the "keepGoing" flag to false. That should do the job.

Comment: i am getting confuse, y don't you just edit my code and post it here

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogInterface listener on ProgressDialog's button, e.g.:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("PAUL app");
            pd.setMessage("Loading data ...");
            pd.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // User has cancelled task ... just quit!
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    return;
                }
            });
            pd.show();
        }
```

Comment: i want to cancel asyntask man, removing activity wont cancel backgound activity